# Why does my TensorFlow profiling timeline show idle times on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

I was profiling the inference latency of a MobileNetV2 model (with a batch size of 20) on my GeForce GTX 1080 GPU.

The TensorFlow timeline shows as follows:
[image: TensorFlow timeline]

I notice that there is quite much empty space in the "stream: all Compute" line, which I think means my GPU was not always busy. What do you think could have been causing this idle time and are there any ways to improve it?

Comment: it's probably waiting for data

Comment: All the intermediate data is kept in GPU memory. Why would it wait for data?

Comment: Hard to tell for sure without more tracing, but GPU also has a simple memory caching hierarchy.  Kept in GPU memory means which level?

Comment: How do you know the data is kept in GPU memory? It seems like the GPU is idle when the CPU is not idle. I''m not an expert, by my guess is that data is being transferred between the CPU and GPU.